# Proof of the derivative of a matrix exponential $\frac d {dt} e^{tA} = Ae^{tA}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

I have the proposition in my book that $$\frac d {dt} e^{tA} = Ae^{tA}$$

The proof provided is somewhat terse. I think I've proved it using games with indices, but the book's preferred proof uses the defn of the derivative.
In particular, I'm annoyed by not understanding this line.
$$\frac d {dt} e^{tA}=e^{tA} \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac {e^{hA} -I}{h}$$ (we're fine and good) 
$$= e^{tA}A$$
(huh?) 
This would imply that the numerator of the limit is equal to $hA$, which I am uncertain of how to prove. I have tried expanding $e^{hA}$ according to the defn of the matrix exponential, but see no further steps.

Comment: By definition,$$\frac{e^{hA}-I}h=A+\frac1{2!}hA^2+\frac1{3!}h^2A^3+\dots\to A$$

Comment: Tre nift! I can grok it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very explicit solution in terms of calculating the matrix exponential.We'll take a real square matrix $A$ and work entirely over the real numbers. There exists a real invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=P\check DP^{-1}$ where $\check D$ is almost diagonal,more precisely, $\check D$ has elements $\lambda_i$ on the leading diagonal, 'rotation' blocks of form $$\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$$  on the leading diagonal, Jordan blocks with a fixed $\lambda_*$ on the leading diagonal and 1's on the super-diagonal and block-Jordan blocks with 'rotation' blocks on the leading diagonal and 2x2 identity matrices $I$ on the super diagonal. Then $$\exp(A)=P\exp(\check D)P^{-1}\text{ and }\exp(At)=P\exp(\check Dt)P^{-1}$$ and $$A\exp(At)=P\check D\exp(\check Dt)P^{-1}$$ When we calculate $\exp(\check D)\text{ and }\exp(\check Dt)$ there is no problem with elements $\lambda_i$ on the leading diagonal-they give $e^{\lambda_i}$ and $e^{\lambda_it}.$ The desired identity is easily checked for those elements. For 'rotation' blocks we use $$\exp(\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}e^a\cos b&-e^a\sin b\\e^a\sin b&e^a\cos b\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\exp(t\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}e^{at}\cos bt&-e^{at}\sin bt\\e^{at}\sin bt&e^{at}\cos bt\end{bmatrix}$$. Again, the desired identity is easily checked for these blocks.Now we look at Jordan blocks $J$ with with a fixed $\lambda_*$ on the leading diagonal and 1's on the super-diagonal. The $m-$th power of $J$ has $\lambda_*^m$ on the leading diagonal and ${m \choose i}\lambda_*^{m-i}$ on the $i-$th super-diagonal. Using the power series for $\exp(J)$ , it follows that $\exp(J)$ is upper-triangular with every element in the upper triangle equal to $e^{\lambda_*}.$ Using the power series for $\exp(tJ)$ , it follows that $\exp(tJ)$ has $e^{\lambda_*t}$ on the leading diagonal and $t^ie^{\lambda_it}$ on the $i-$th super-diagonal. Taking the derivative of this expression it is easy to check that exactly the same result is obtained by multiplying $\exp(tJ)$ by$J.$ Combining these Jordan block results with our earlier result tor 'rotation' blocks, we can establish the desired formula for Jordan block Jordan blocks.

Comment: You used several words I'm not familiar with, "almost diagonal"--Jordan form?, "leading diagonal"--presumably the diagonal?, "super diagonal"--the entries above the diagonal?, $\check D$--is this to denote "almost diagonal?", "rotation blocks"--unsure, $\lambda_*$--this may be standard somewhere, "block-jordan blocks"--jordan blocks?, "Jordan block Jordan blocks"--ditto. May I ask whether I've interpreted your terms correctly?

Comment: "almost diagonal" not used in a technical sense.I just meant that the matrix wasn't too far off from being diagonal "leading diagonal", "main diagonal" synonyms in the literature for "diagonal" i.e. elements in row j & column j  for any j"super diagonal" elements in row j & column j+1 for any j,  D with a check mark on top used for an "almost diagonal" matrix "rotation block" the 2x2 matrix M with row 1 [a,-b], row 2 [b,a] called "rotation" because if we use polar coordinates and put a=r cos (theta),b=r sin (theta ) then M=rM' where M' is matrix with ******* continued in next comment

Comment: row 1=[cos(theta),-sin(theta)] ,row2=[sin(theta),cos(theta)] ,then M' is the matrix that represents a rotation through an angle theta about the origin in 2-space, used subscript  * on lambda to emphasize that in the block we were using one particular eigenvalue throughout, not various eigenvalues lambda subscript i at various rows/columns within the block, "i-th super diagonal" elements in row j, column i+j for any i,j, "jordan block"    of matrix 'check D' is a sub-matrix J with a particular eigenvalue along the diagonal and 1's along the super-diagonal ******* continued in next comment

Comment: @ 71-104:positioned with top left (& also bottom right) element of J on diagonal of 'check D'  "block Jordan block" of 'check D' is a sub-matrix J' of 'check D' . J' is partitioned int 2x2 blocks with a particular 'rotation' block along the diagonal and 2x2 identity matrices along the super- diagonal. J' is also positioned on the diagonal of 'check D'. If we can use complex numbers in P and 'check D', then all we need in 'check D' are diagonal elements and Jordan blocks. If we must use only real numbers, then we also need 'rotation' matrices & 'block-Jordan blocks' in 'check D'.